# Rescue Math::Domain Error

Tags: ruby

i have this method to find angles of triangle given three sides.I want rescue `Math::DomainError` and print 0 instead:

```
def triangle_type (a, b, c)
  p first=Math.acos((b**2+c**2-a**2) / (2.0*b*c)) * (180 / Math::PI)
  p second=Math.acos((c**2+a**2-b**2) / (2.0*c*a)) * (180 / Math::PI)
  p third=180-(first+second)
end
triangle_type(7,3,2) will produce `Numerical argument is out of domain - "acos" (Math::DomainError)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def triangle_type (a, b, c)
  begin
    p first=Math.acos((b**2+c**2-a**2) / (2.0*b*c)) * (180 / Math::PI)
    p second=Math.acos((c**2+a**2-b**2) / (2.0*c*a)) * (180 / Math::PI)
    p third=180-(first+second)
  rescue Math::DomainError => e  
    puts 0
  end
end

triangle_type(7, 3, 2)
```

Comment: can begin and rescue be used inside the method?